# How do I upload multiple (different) files to Cloud storage firebase?

Tags: arrays, firebase, closures, swiftui, completionhandler

I would like to upload multiple files at once to cloud storage. I have an open panel already. I use that to select the files and with the selected files I have an upload file. I thought a `ForEach()` would work but it either doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong. I also tried Completion Handlers and closures but I don't understand those yet. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at Help Center's [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: and see... [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Had to make an escaping closure to loop the amount of files you're trying to upload. ex:

```
//define
func Upload(closure:(int)->Bool,numbers:[int]){
for num in numbers{
 if closure(num){
   //urls[index/num/whatever you call it]
  //upload info with the index (it'll loop that many times)
}
}
}
```

using: `self.UploadTest(file: { (num) -> Bool in
                        return num <= urlArray.count}, urls: [0,1])`